# Cox-Hazard Ratio differences in Software suits; Manual calculation

Tags: r, cox-model, sas, hazard, proportional-hazards

Working in clinical research my task is to calculate the Hazard ratio, better to check the calculations of someone else. This first calculation was based on ARM=(3 different treatments) with only t=(end-times) and censored data of format CNSR=(a,b,...) in {0,1} in the software suite SAS.
I redid the work in NCSS and R, all three computations totally different.

Please let me post my R-Code:

`library(survival)
    data<-filter_na_values(data)
    surv_obj<-Surv(data$times,data$censor)
    result<-coxph(surv_obj~ARM,data)`

Resulting from this code I got coefficients which tends to resemble the NCSS and SAS output at least in direction, yet have a high error rate. All 3 outputs could yield different results.

Please help getting insights into this problem, I would be especially interested in literature on how to calc cox-hazard ratio manually; code samples of how a similiar setting is done right, criterias to check the output by and additional packages to redo the calculations on. All three treatment ARM's are varying in size, if it matters.

Thx for the flowers.

Comment: found out what was going on here, censoring was applied the other way around